# Reading updated reference values in PHP extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I am writing a PHP extension to track the database call and retrieved data for mysqli extension. For that, I have updated the method handler for mysqli::bind_result and mysqli::fetch method, and introduced proxy methods.

Now in the proxy method for mysqli::bind_result, I am keeping the input references as shown below:

```
void proxy_mysqli_stmt_bind_result(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS)
{
    original_bind_result(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU);

    zval *args;
    int argc;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), "z/+", &args, &argc) == FAILURE) 
    {
       return;
    }

    HOOK_MYSQLI_G(args) = args;
    HOOK_MYSQLI_G(argc) = argc;        
}
```

In the proxy method of mysqli::fetch, I am reading the updated values -

```
void proxy_mysqli_stmt_fetch(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS)
{
   original_fetch(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAM_PASSTHRU);

   if (Z_TYPE_P(return_value) != IS_TRUE) return;

   zval *args = HOOK_MYSQLI_G(args);
   int  argc = HOOK_MYSQLI_G(argc);

   for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; i++)
   {
       log("%s", Z_STRVAL_P(Z_REFVAL_P(&args[i]));
   }
}
```

PHP script -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password);
$mysqli->select_db($dbname);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $firstname, $lastname);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $firstname, $location);
}
```

I have two records in the DB for testing purpose. The output for my extension in the logfile, (wrong output)

> First record: id1, name1, lastname1
>
> Second record: %s (%s)\n, name1, lastname1

if I remove printf from the php script then, output is as expected -

> First record: id1, name1, lastname1
>
> Second record: id2, name2, lastname2

What's the issue here? I am keeping reference varables for bind_result/fetch methods, why printf method is updating the references?